# Как переписать переменную при наследовании в PHP?

Tags: php

```
class A {
    protected $var_test = ['a'];
}

class B extends A {
    protected $var_test = array_merge($parent::$var_test, ['b']); //Тут и есть проблема
}
```

Как такое сделать?

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Проблема - ок. А что зна проблема? Зачем же остальных заставлять гадать, а не чётко ясно описать конкретно что не так?

Comment: Что именно не ясно? Хочу в переменную `$var_test` дописать дополнительные значения, в классе `B`. Как это сделать. Метод, например, легко переписать. То есть `B->$var_test = A->var_test + другие.`

Comment: Что именно не ясно..... вот к тебе подходит мама и говорит: у меня комп не работает......что ты из этого поймёшь?

Comment: Также и тут...."Тут и есть проблема" .... какая проблема? Разве тебе ошибок не показывает? показывает. Так напиши что за ошибка.

Comment: Да, но если она скажет, что grub полетел, после apt upgrade, то пойму. Я же не пишу: PHP СЛАМАЛСЯ...

Comment: ввооооот видишь....она уточняяяет, что grub полетел, а не что монитор выключен или провод питания отошёл.........так и ты: напиши ты ошибку, подробно - что не так. Ошибок может быть миллион, и без оных гадать можно до самой смерти. А описание ошибки как минимум даст понимание в какую сторону копать

Comment: "Я же не пишу: PHP СЛАМАЛСЯ..." --- ну отлично, мама подходит и говорит: ВИНДА СЛОМАЛААСЯ..  Твои предположения?

Comment: Обновление) В любом случае, с вопросом, Вы помогли, за что Вам спасибо. Спор я, пожалуй, оставлю.

Comment: окей. в следующий раз пиши подробнее: что есть, какая задача, что делаешь, что не получается и обязательно все ошибки, которые появляются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражения запрещены для указания значений свойств. Поэтому если поле вычсисляемое - придётся правило инициализации задавать в констркуторе.